# What is wrong with this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, lambda

I am really struggling to understand why, when I change my code to use a lamdba expression, it doesn't work.

This code works and prints on console:

```
object dummy = new object();
InterServer.ExecuteDataReader(new InterServerRequest(ServerID.a_01, "dbo.getbooks") 
    { 
        Params = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
            { "Tool", "d1" }, 
            { "Loc", locale == string.Empty ? null : locale } } 
    },
    (_, reader) =>
        {
            reader.AsEnumerable(r => (r.GetString(r.GetOrdinal("book")))).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            return new Response(dummy);
        }
    );
```

This code has been changed to use a lambda expression; it doesn't print anything, I don't understand why:

```
InterServer.ExecuteDataReader(new InterServerRequest(ServerID.a_01, "dbo.getbooks")
    { 
        Params = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
            { "Tool", "d1" }, 
            { "Loc", locale == string.Empty ? null : locale } } 
    },
    (_, reader) =>
        {
            return new Response(new Action(() => 
                reader.AsEnumerable(r =>(r.GetString(r.GetOrdinal("book")))).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)));
        }
    );
```

This is really driving me mad as I don't see if I am doing anything wrong.  Can someone help?

Thanks,
AG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve by making it use a lambda expression?

In this example, the `Action` is not invoked, therefore nothing happens. When the `Action` will be invoked you'll see the output.

The `Action` is not executed implicitly.

For example:

```
public void Call()
{
    // Call with int argument 1
    DoSomething(1);

    // Call with Func that returns 1
    // It'll never produce the value unless Func is invoked
    DoSomething(new Func<int>(() => 1));

    // Call with Func explicitly invoked
    // In this case the body of the lambda will be executed
    DoSomething(new Func<int>(() => 1).Invoke());
}

public void DoSomething(object obj)
{

}
```

Calling the `Response` constructor with `Action` will actually send the `Action`. If `Response` has an overload that invokes it and uses the return value, then the `Action` will appear only when the `Response` actually uses it (not necessary during the constructor call).

In your example, the work will be done anyway during the call to `(_, reader) => ...` so there is no work done "too early".

To make it clear (last sample I add :) ):

```
public void Call()
{
    DoSomething(new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Arrived")));
}

public void DoSomething(Action obj)
{
    int x = 0; // Nothing printed yet
    Action storedAction = obj; // Nothing printed yet
    storedAction.Invoke(); // Message will be printed
}
```

Unless `Response` expects an `Action` it'll never get to execute its body.

Comment: So what i am trying is my (_,reader) delegate return a Response(object obj). Hope thats fine. So in my 2nd example me rather evaluating something first and then returning a result wrapped in Response i am trying to do that work inside Response by calling Action delegate and returning Response as a result.

so something like (_,reader) => new Response(new Action(() => domy workas i dont need to return anything ).
Hope this helps you to let me know what am i doign wrong.

Comment: Many thanks Elisha, Got it Now i can do something like this and it works 

new Response( new Action(() => reader.AsEnumerable(r =>
                                                                                                                        (
                                                                                                                            r.GetString(r.GetOrdinal("main_book"))
                                                                                                                        )).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)).DynamicInvoke(null))

Comment: Cool, but now it'll behave similar to the original implementation. The Invoke executes it immediately, meaning in both cases it will run just before Response it created.